# Chrome not rendering SVG as exptected

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have a problem with rendering SVG image, but only in Chrome (version 87). It did work in early version of Chrome, like version 86.
It does render as it should be in Firefox.
The URL of the SVG is:
https://svgshare.com/i/RuQ.svg

At Chrome, the sky-blue circle is not displayed,
[image: chrome]
While in Firefox it does.
[image: firebox]

Also, here's a simple HTML page with how I use the SVG.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>

  <body>
    <img height="50px" width="50px" src="https://svgshare.com/i/RuQ.svg"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas for what might be wrong in the SVG?

Comment: Report chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SVG looks like it was produced by Adobe Illustrator. While Robert Longson is formally right that this is a Chrome bug, the blame goes fully to Adobe.

For documentation: this is what the program exported to SVG. I have already shortened the code by ca. 50% removing unused definitions:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 43 43">
  <defs>
    <style>
    .cls-3{fill:#040f21;}
    .cls-4{mask:url(#mask-2);}
    .cls-5{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}
    .cls-7{filter:url(#luminosity-noclip-2);}
    </style>
    <filter id="luminosity-noclip-2" x="2.36" y="-16315" width="39.63" height="32766" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-color="#fff" result="bg"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="bg"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask-2" x="2.36" y="-16315" width="39.63" height="32766" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g class="cls-7"/>
    </mask>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="22.17" y1="60.87" x2="22.17" y2="-17.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0.21" stop-color="#3f97f5"/>
      <stop offset="0.83" stop-color="#3fa9f5"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <title>Dlogo</title>
  <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
    <path class="cls-3" d="M28.43,31.83a23.24,23.24,0,0,1-5.41.78c-6.12,0-8.86-2.07-8.86-11.48S17.44,9.44,23.34,9.44a18.52,18.52,0,0,1,5.09.71l-.51,3.28a16.24,16.24,0,0,0-4.22-.61c-3.62,0-5.16,1.13-5.16,8.18S20,29.22,23.7,29.22a15.69,15.69,0,0,0,4.22-.67Z"/>
    <g class="cls-4">
      <path class="cls-5" d="M22.17,41.31A19.81,19.81,0,1,1,42,21.5,19.83,19.83,0,0,1,22.17,41.31Zm0-35.21a15.4,15.4,0,1,0,15.4,15.4A15.41,15.41,0,0,0,22.17,6.1Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The second `path` is the only member of a group `.cls-5`, which is masked with `#mask-2`.

This luminosity mask contains an empty group, making the mask by default hiding all content that is masked. To counteract this, the group is filtered with `#luminosity-noclip-2`. The filter floods an area in user space of 39.63 by 32766 with white, then copies the group contents (nothing) on top. As a result, the luminosity mask should be filled white, making all masked content visible, completely unaltered.

In short: nothing but useless junk. In theory, it does nothing. In practice, it wastes computing resources and gives oportunity to almost every bug renderers might have to bite you.

If this is what Illustrator produces nowadays, throw it out of the window to never use again.

A clean SVG that is identical in all aspects to the intended one looks like this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 43 43">
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="22.17" y1="60.87" x2="22.17" y2="-17.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0.21" stop-color="#3f97f5"/>
    <stop offset="0.83" stop-color="#3fa9f5"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <title>Dlogo</title>
  <path style="fill:#040f21;" d="M28.43,31.83a23.24,23.24,0,0,1-5.41.78c-6.12,0-8.86-2.07-8.86-11.48S17.44,9.44,23.34,9.44a18.52,18.52,0,0,1,5.09.71l-.51,3.28a16.24,16.24,0,0,0-4.22-.61c-3.62,0-5.16,1.13-5.16,8.18S20,29.22,23.7,29.22a15.69,15.69,0,0,0,4.22-.67Z"/>
  <path style="fill:url(#linear-gradient);" d="M22.17,41.31A19.81,19.81,0,1,1,42,21.5,19.83,19.83,0,0,1,22.17,41.31Zm0-35.21a15.4,15.4,0,1,0,15.4,15.4A15.41,15.41,0,0,0,22.17,6.1Z"/>
</svg>
```